# ReplaceAll Elements in an Indexed Vector

Tags: vector

Following up on [how to define symbolic vectors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282179/how-are-symbolic-vectors-defined)

Let **x** be an *n*-dimensional symbolic vector, where *n* is a positive integer large enough to be a massive pain in the butt.

```mathematica
n = 42;
xs = Array[Indexed[x, #] &, n]
```

[image]

If I were to evaluate a function on **x** with some value, I would replace each element by hand using the shorthand notation for `ReplaceAll`.

For example, if I take the sum of squares on **x** at the zero vector, I would type

```mathematica
Transpose[xs] . xs /. { \
xs[[1]]  -> 0,  xs[[2]] -> 0,  xs[[3]] -> 0,  xs[[4]] -> 0,  xs[[5]] -> 0, \
xs[[6]]  -> 0,  xs[[7]] -> 0,  xs[[8]] -> 0,  xs[[9]] -> 0, xs[[10]] -> 0, \
xs[[11]] -> 0, xs[[12]] -> 0, xs[[13]] -> 0, xs[[14]] -> 0, xs[[15]] -> 0, \
xs[[16]] -> 0, xs[[17]] -> 0, xs[[18]] -> 0, xs[[19]] -> 0, xs[[20]] -> 0, \
xs[[21]] -> 0, xs[[22]] -> 0, xs[[23]] -> 0, xs[[24]] -> 0, xs[[25]] -> 0, \
xs[[26]] -> 0, xs[[27]] -> 0, xs[[28]] -> 0, xs[[29]] -> 0, xs[[30]] -> 0, \
xs[[31]] -> 0, xs[[32]] -> 0, xs[[33]] -> 0, xs[[34]] -> 0, xs[[35]] -> 0, \
xs[[36]] -> 0, xs[[37]] -> 0, xs[[38]] -> 0, xs[[39]] -> 0, xs[[40]] -> 0, \
xs[[41]] -> 0, xs[[42]] -> 0}
```

[image]

**Is there a shortcut to ReplaceAll the elements in the vector?**

Comment: `Transpose[xs] . xs /. Thread[xs -> 0]` or `Transpose[xs] . xs /. _Indexed ->0`?

Comment: Try: `xs /. Indexed[x, _] -> 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FullForm of

[image: Mathematica graphics]

is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hence you can do

```
n = 10;
xs = Array[Indexed[x, #] &, n];
res = Transpose[xs] . xs
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now to replaced each $x_{i}^{n}$ just do

```
res /. Indexed[x, any1_]^any2_. :> 1
(*10*)
```

The above replaces each entry by 1.  You can replace each element by zero also.

```
 res /. Indexed[x, any1_]^any2_. :> 0
 (*0*)
```

You can replace the above using any other way you want using the named patterns `any1_` and `any2_` also.

For example to replace each element by the power it has

```
res /. Indexed[x, any1_]^any2_. :> any2
(*20*)
```

To replace each by its index

```
res /. Indexed[x, any1_]^any2_. :> any1
(* 55 *)
```

and so on.

I am not sure if this is what you meant or not.

Comment: +1 There is no distinction between row and column vectors. Consequently, use the simpler `res = xs . xs` And if a pattern name on the LHS of a rule is not used on the RHS of the rule, then the pattern does not need a name; e.g.,  `res /. Indexed[x, _]^_. :> 1` or `res /. Indexed[x, _]^any2_. :> any2` suffice.